# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux-form

I am trying to dispatch an action when I submit a form but I'm getting this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function
```

This is my class:

```
/**
 *
 * CatalogPage
 *
 */

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { Form, Control } from 'react-redux-form/immutable';

import injectSaga from 'utils/injectSaga';
import injectReducer from 'utils/injectReducer';
import makeSelectCatalogPage from './selectors';
import reducer from './reducer';
import saga from './saga';

export class CatalogPage extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

  handleSubmit = (user) => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'test action' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form
        model="user"
        onSubmit={(user) => this.handleSubmit(user)}
      >
        <label htmlFor=".firstName">First name:</label>
        <Control.text model=".firstName" id=".firstName"/>

        <label htmlFor=".lastName">Last name:</label>
        <Control.text model=".lastName" id=".lastName"/>

        <button type="submit">
          Finish registration!
        </button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

CatalogPage.propTypes = {};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  catalogpage: makeSelectCatalogPage(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'catalogPage', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'catalogPage', saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(CatalogPage);
```

I thought that the compose function at the bottom would connect my component to the store and thus have access to the dispatch function through this.props.dispatch. But it's not working, what am I missing?

Thanks!

**EDIT: I've changed handleSubmit to arrow function but problem still persists**

```
handleSubmit = (user) => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'test action' });
  }
```

**EDIT: The problem resolved itself**

Something to mention is that react-boiler-plate is not as user-friendly as one might expect. There's alot of weird things that are happening and took me a long time to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the misunderstanding of a class method and the way that React manages instances.

You can do three things to avoid this problem:

1) Convert the (handleSubmit) function to an arrow function so in that case, it won't have its own `this`.

```
handleSubmit = (user) => { // ...logic here }
```

2) Create a constructor inside the component and do the next step:

```
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
```

In this case, you attach `this` to the function each time an instance is created.

3) When you call the method inside the render use the `.bind()` to bind `this`:

```
onSubmit={(user) => this.handleSubmit.bind(this, user)}
```

Comment: I have added the => like this 

 handleSubmit = (user) => {
    dispatch({type: 'hello world'});
  };

and i'm still getting the same error. I've edited my class to show what i have now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need mapDispatchToProps if you just want to inject dispatch into your component. You would use that when you want to bind your action creators before injecting them into your component. Just pass mapStateToProps with no second param and you should be good.

You also need to do what Jose Gomez suggests below. Basically you need to bind this. The easiest way is to just change handleSubmit to an arrow function

```
handleSubmit = user => {
...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? This is what i currently have:

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

Do you mean to do this:

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, null); ??

Comment: I mean you don't need that second param at all. You can do connect(mapStateToProps). The second param is if you are binding your action creators. I usually pass in my action creators object and then it will bind them and inject them for you. I never actually pass dispatch into my components.

Comment: Please help me sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67180197/how-to-pass-props-data-from-render-to-handlesubmit-function-in-redux